# Ruby: select a hash from inside an array

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
response = [{"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955}, {"label" => "dog", "name"=>"rex", "id" => 550081}]
```

How do I select the hash that contains the label cat? I know `response.first` will give me the same result, but I want to search the by label.

Thanks!

Deb

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
response.find {|x| x['label'] == 'cat' } #=> {"label"=>"cat", "name"=>"kitty", "id"=>189955}
```

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
response.select { |x| x["label"] == "cat" }
```

Comment: select works too, but it returns an array, so I'm going with "find" in this particular case. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, `Array#find` returns the first match or nil, while `Array#select` and `Array#find_all` return an array of all matching elements.

Comment: And it's also worth noting that a synonym for `Array#find` is `Array#detect`.