# Create dynamic sidebar based on hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Supposed I have a set of hashes such as this:

```
@demo = [{"category"=>"history", "title"=>"world war 2"}, {"category"=>"history", "title"=>"world war 1"}, {"category"=>"chemistry","title"=>"chemistry experiments" }]
```

and a sidebar like this:

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
    <li class="start ">
     <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
        <span class="title">Example</span>
    </li>
<ul>
```

1) How can I display the my sidebar based on the key "category" of hash, without repetition?

2) I have other data in the hash, how can I create views, so that when I click on the value in the sidebar, for example "history", it will link to the page where it display all data that has the category "history"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I display the my sidebar based on the key "category" of hash, without repetition

You have to be clearer when defining this functionality.

You have two sets of `history` category objects (and, by the way, you have an array of hashes)...

```
@demo = [{"category"=>"history", "title"=>"world war 2"}, {"category"=>"history", "title"=>"world war 1"}]
```

... so which one do you want to show?

The problem with arrays is they are meant to be [constructs of unsorted (*not* unordered) data](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_arrays.htm) -

> Arrays are ordered, integer-indexed collections of any object.

This means you cannot load data out of an array by "calling" it - they are dumb, and are not meant to know which data are inside the overall array.

---

**[Ruby: select a hash from inside an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419050/ruby-select-a-hash-from-inside-an-array)**

You *can* perform "find" functionality on the array, as you would a collection from a model etc:

```
category = @demo.find {|x| x['category'] == 'category' } #=> [{"category"=>"history", "title"=>"world war 2"}, {"category"=>"history", "title"=>"world war 1"}]
```

This will return another array which you'll have to either loop through, or **be more specific** about invoking.

--

So you'll end up with something like this:

```
<% history = @demo.find { |x| x['category'] == "history" } 
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
    <li class="start ">
     <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
        <%= content_tag :span, history.first.title, class: "title" %> #-> World War 2 (remember, Arrays are unsorted)
    </li>
<ul>
```

If you just wanted to loop through it all, you'd be able to do the following:

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
    <% categories = @demo.uniq { |s| s.category }
    <% categories.each do |category| %>
        <li class="start ">
            <%= link_to category.title, category %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
<ul>
```

---

> I have other data in the hash, how can I create views, so that when I click on the value in the sidebar, for example "history", it will link to the page where it display all data that has the category "history"

This, my friend, is the essence of Rails.

If you're asking questions like this, you need to read up on how Rails works at its core.

Here's the code I'd use, I'll let you work it out:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories #-> url.com/categories/:id

#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @category = Category.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/categories/show.html.erb
<%= @category.title %>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do it in this way. i have just take some example `HTML` code for demonstartion you can used your own.

1)firstly create a hash with link of current page like

```
@demo = [{"category"=>"history", "title"=>"world war 2", :path => histories_path}]
```

2)for selecting uniq category

```
@uniq_demo  = @demo.uniq! {|e| e["category"] }
```

3)after that you can iterate trough complete hash as

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
  <% @uniq_demo.each do |menu| %> 
    <% if menu["category"].present? %>
     <li class="start ">
       <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
        <a href='<%= menu["path"]>'><span class='<%= menu["title"]%>'><%= menu["category"]%></span></a>
     </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I remove duplicate values of "category"? For example I have 2 hashes containing "history", but I only want to show one menu in my side bar.

Comment: in that case you can select it uniq as adding(editing) in answer